# Using 2 images in a block with sheadawson Silverstripe block module?

Tags: silverstripe

I am using sheadawson/silverstripe-blocks module: https://github.com/sheadawson/silverstripe-blocks

I am trying to have it so the user can add 2x images to a block. For some reason it will only pull through the first image.

Both of them are definitely uploaded as per the screenshot:

[image]

**TwoImagesLeftTextRightBlock.php**

```
<?php

class TwoImagesLeftTextRightBlock extends Block {

    private static $db = array(
        'Title' => 'Varchar(255)',
        'Summary' => 'HTMLText',
    );

    private static $has_one = array(
        'Image' => 'Image',
        'SecondImage' => 'Image'
    );

}
```

**Template for the block:**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 ptb50">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <div class="block-right-title">$Title</div>
                    <div class="block-left-text">
                        $Summary
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <img class="block-icon" src="$Image.URL" alt="">
                    <img class="block-icon" src="$SecondImage.URL" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Inspecting the code you can see it only pulls through the first image... Any ideas on how to get both working?

[image]

Comment: In your inspected code, thats a different image to what you have uploaded for "Image".

Comment: Yip sorry realise that. I changed the images after I took the screenshot of the uploaded images. Still get the same result e.g first image comes through fine and second has no src... Real weird..

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with your code. Have you tried running a dev/build and flush? I've had an issue like this once or twice with SilverStripe that I was never able to explain... I eventually fixed it by renaming the field to something else, in your case maybe trying dropping "SecondImage" and starting again with "ImageTwo" or similar.